# Same property in two different tabs (divs). Property is null when tab 2 is posted to action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I post back to the server when tab2 is active `viewModel.FirstName` is null in the action method. How do you tell the modelbinder that it should take `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)` from tab2 when that tab is active? Everything works fine for tab1.

jQuery hide() and show() are used for switching between tabs.

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewModel)
```

View

```
<div id="tab1">
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
</div>
<div id="tab2">
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have both FirstName input fields inside the same form.

Something like:

```
<form>
  <div id="tab1">
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
  </div>
  <div id="tab2">
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
  </div>
</form>
```

When you post this, the form is submitted as:

```
FirstName=valueFromField01&FirstName=valueFromField02
```

From the behavior you are describing, it seems that once the model binder sets the FirstName field in your `MyViewModel`, it ignores the second one (but I'm not really sure about that).

Solutions:

1. Rather than have a form with different tabs inside of it, have a form inside each tab. This will ensure you only have one FirstName inside a form.
2. Update the model so that you get both fields. You would need to use an array of string: `string[] FirstName`.

**Update:**
Instead of updating your ViewModel, it might be easier to simply add another parameter to your action method so you can get both FirstName values and then figure out which one was actually provided:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewModel, string [] FirstName).
```

Then you can have logic in your action method to set the FirstName in your viewModel:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName[0]))
{
   viewModel.FirstName = FirstName[0]
}
else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName[1]))
{
   viewModel.FirstName = FirstName[1];
}
```

Comment: "It sounds like you have both FirstName input fields inside the same form." that is correct. And in this particular case I need both input fields to be in the same form.

Comment: Updated with code example to show how it can work when you have both FirstName fields on the same form.

Comment: Tested your nr 2 suggestion... the values are passed correctly but instead I loose validation (property decorated with [Required] attribute) on FirstName.. is there a way to individually add validation to the string objects that are inside the string[] array?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that disabling the duplicated name form elements. By default, disabled form elemnts will not be passed to the request, and your Controller problably will receive the name corectly from the tab2 when it is shown active.

So. here follows one example

```
$('#tab1')
     .hide()
     .find('input[name="FirstName]"') 
          .prop('disabled',true);

$('#tab2').show()
     .find('input[name="FirstName]"') 
          .prop('disabled',false);
```

Latter I suggest you should wrap this behaviour inside a function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This seems to work pretty well..  need to test it more though.. I think I prefer this method since you only post the variables that you need from each tab.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you have liked this approach !